# HTTP header in Javascript files with puma on development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, puma, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I have a Rails application, which uses the comfortable mexican sofa CMS. I needed server side events with `ActionController::Live`, so i use Puma instead of the standard Webrick.

Sometimes some of the javascript assets get served as `plain/text` and contain the HTTP header like in the following file:

```
0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/javascript
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 May 2014 09:39:06 GMT
ETag: "9fad3cb6ef7afd353261ec38da25c2e9"
X-Request-Id: 043c6782-4e7c-471a-b6ba-6ea142242fa4
X-Runtime: 0.032228
Content-Length: 820

(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('form').on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    ...
```

Any ideas what's the matter and how to fix this?

As it seems this only occurs in Chrome. Firefox and Safari don't have any problems.

Comment: Is this for js served by CMS controller? It used `text/javascript` as content type before and it seems to be obsolete. Master branch has it changed to `application/javascript`. See if it fixes it.

Comment: @Grocery: No it's javascript, i included via `javascript_include_tag` in a partial.